# TikZ Qtree subcaptions

Tags: formatting, tikz-trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

[image: Tree diagram subcaptions]I'm using the TikZ Qtree package for making syntactic tree diagrams. Am wondering how to add subcaptions for individual node labels, such as shown in attached photo, as well as formating them (strikethrough, bold, etc.). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You don't give an example, but if you add

```
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
```

you can allow explicit tabular newlines in node labels.

I've used the `ulem` package for strikeout, and made two macro wrappers to format interpretable and uninterpretable features.

If you haven't committed lots of time to using `tikz-qtree` you might want to consider using the more powerful `forest` package instead. The syntax is basically the same except node labels don't require `.` prefixes, and no extra code is required to allow tabular newlines in node labels. I've added a `forest` example too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand\iF[1]{[{\bfseries#1}]}
\newcommand\uF[1]{[{\emph{\sout{#1}}}\kern1pt]}
\newcommand\1{$'$}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}% needed for tikz-qtree
\begin{document}
\Tree
[.TP    [.PRN\\it\\\iF{3-Pers}\\\iF{Sg-Num}\\\uF{Nom Case} ]
        [.T\1
            [.T\\\textsc{be}\\\iF{Pres-Tns}\\\uF{3-Pers}\\\uF{Sg-Num}\\\uF{EPP} ]
            [.VP
                [.V\\raining ]
                [.PRN\\\sout{it} ]
            ]
        ]
]

\begin{forest}
[TP     [PRN\\it\\\iF{3-Pers}\\\iF{Sg-Num}\\\uF{Nom Case} ]
        [T\1
            [T\\\textsc{be}\\\iF{Pres-Tns}\\\uF{3-Pers}\\\uF{Sg-Num}\\\uF{EPP} ]
            [VP
                [V\\raining ]
                [PRN\\\sout{it} ]
            ]
        ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Alan, thanks so much for your response. I have committed some time to TikZ-Qtree, but forest seems like a better alternative. Thanks also for the code. I can't get it to work on my end, despite installing [ulem] and [forest]. Even the Qtree code won't render for me. Any ideas as to why this might be? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @luhausler without any more information it's hard to diagnose. Do you get errors? Is your TeX distribution up-to-date?